# Whats the difference between UInt8 and uint8_t

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

What is the differnce between `UInt8` and `uint8_t`, or `UInt16` and `unit16_t`?

What does the `_t` imply?

Comment: `_t` = Cross platform implementation of a standard data type.

Comment: I think `_t` stands for `type` and it is a convention used on Linux systems and on many places in `C` and `C++` standard. The difference between `Uint8` and `uint8_t` will depend on implementation, but usually they will both be 8 bit unsigned integers. Also `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` are defined by C (and maybe C++) standard in `stdint.h` header, `Uint8` and `Uint16` are non-standard as far as I know.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In C99 the available basic integer types (the ones without _t) were deemed insufficient, because their actual sizes may vary across different systems.

So, the C99 standard includes definitions of several new integer types to enhance the portability of programs. The new types are especially useful in embedded environments.

All of the new types are suffixed with a _t and are guaranteed to be defined uniformly across all systems.

For more info see the [fixed-width integer types section of the wikipedia article on Stdint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#stdint.h).

Comment: `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` are indeed part of C99. That said, the need for fixed sizes predates C99, so different code bases dealt with this need by providing their own types. OS X defines `UInt8` and `UInt16` in /usr/include/MacTypes.h.

Comment: "All of the new types are suffixed with a _t and are guaranteed to be defined uniformly across all systems." is not true, there are `(u)int_leastN_t` and `(u)int_fastN_t`. You meant only the fixed-width types.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't trying to say anything about their sizes being the same across all systems. The actual sizes are only guaranteed uniform for fixed-width (exact-width) types  as you mention. However, the definitions are the same across all systems. For example int_leastN_t is defined to be the smallest type available in the implementation. The definition is the same no matter the system.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that the `uintX_t` types are standard C defined by C99 and later while `UIntX` is not. This has implications for how portable the code is. Code using `uintX_t` types can be compiled on any standard C compiler without any other dependencies. Code that uses `UIntX` on the other hand, must either define those types itself, or depend on some library or framework that does so.

I don't think Objective-C as such defines any extra integer types, but it may well be that your framework (Coacoa, OpenStep?) does so. If your code makes no sense outside of the framework, use what's idiomatic in the framework context. Otherwise try to stick to the standard types.

Answer (score 0):

normally they are used as a typedef datatypes. "_t" stand for a typedef datatype.
we give such name so that they can be used and read easily across all the file or huge code base.

*UInt8 and uint8_t - Char*

**typedef unit8_t unsigned char**

*UInt16 and unit16_t*

**typedef unit16_t unsigned int** ( on a 16 bit compiler)

Comment: Please, add some reference of "_t stand for a typedef datatype" and "read easily across all the file or huge code base".

Comment: Are you sure that name of `typedef`ined datatype does not come last?  I mean like `typedef unsigned char unit8_t;`.